# Knitting error when knitting html on RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I've been a regular R user for 1.5 years. Never seen this happen and have no idea how to fix it. I've read the whole Internet in search of a solution without luck. I have tried restarting my computer and reinstalling RStudio. I am able to knit any .Rmd as a .pdf or .html the first time I try it, but subsequent tries fail with the error messages below. This happens with both tried-and-true .Rmd that have worked previously as well as new template .Rmd files created through RStudio's File-->New option. If I re-install RStudio, it allows knitting of any .Rmd file again on the first try.

```
Loading required package: knitr
Warning message:
package ‘knitr’ was built under R version 3.2.3 

processing file: HW16.Rmd
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: HW16.md

[1] "HW16.md"
Error generating HTML preview for ~/Dropbox/MyProjects/spring2016/advancedMachineLearning/HW16.Rmd r error 4 (R code execution error)
```

The console generates:
[image]

Comment: Maybe some of the R code in your document breaks the knitting procedure? Does the evaluated R code do anything with default libraries, system options, etc? A good way to check would be to see if you can knit a *different* document more than once after reinstall.

Comment: No, none of the R code is breaking the knitting procedure. I tried .Rmd files that have worked before as well as new, Rstudio-templated .Rmd files. The same problem happens to both types of files. I am unable to knit any document more than once after reinstalling.

Comment: are you caching any results or changing the default directories in some config file, rprofile, etc?

Comment: nope. Won't even work for knit attempt 2+ with the RStudio .Rmd template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: delete R from your computer. You do not need to re-install RStudio. To delete R on my Mac, I went to `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/` then deleted the folders "3.2.x" (these stand for the version of R. It is possible that you have more than one version installed). Next, I re-installed R using `brew` in the terminal.

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install r
```

Open RStudio. Knit any .Rmd that is known to work, or a fresh .Rmd generated by RStudio. Knit again. Problem solved!